# What parameter is affecting the accuracy when training faces,and how do I improve it?

Tags: python, opencv

So here's my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")

face_cascade = 
cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            #print(label, path)
            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1
            id_ = label_ids[label]  
            #print(label_ids)      
            #y_labels.append(label)# some number
            #x_train.append(path)# verify this image
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L")
                size = (550, 550)
                final_image = pil_image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                image_array = np.array(final_image, "uint8")
                #print(image_array)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=3)

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id_)
```

When I start to train the images I stored in a folder, the result is that not all of the images are trained, and the accuracy of recognizing faces wasn't that good.

There's some parameter here that I don't quite understand, but seems to be affecting the training result a lot.

Is there any way to improve the accuracy?

This is my first time asking a question, so if there's a similar question existing or not typing in the right format, please inform me. Thank you for your time reading this.

Comment: there is no training in your code, is it?

Comment: It's only a part of my code. Should I post all of them to make it clear?

Comment: you should at least tell what you are doing since we can't guees what kind of training you perform. SVM? Haar-Cascades? Lbp-Cascades? DNN? So we neither know what kind of parameters are available and which ones you use in what way.

Comment: One thing that looks suspicious to me is, that you rescale your image to (550,550) which might mean that your detected faces (that you use for training?) might be distorted, if they are detected at all.

Comment: the "Image.ANTIALIAS" actually prevents the image from distortion.

Comment: are you sure? I dont know pil well, so maybe I am wrong, but anti-aliasing typically does only reduce interpolation artifacts,.it does not fix the aspect ratio. If you have for ecample a 1000x500 pixel image and you rescale it to 550x550, faces of the original image will appear stretched, because the aspect ratio changes.

Comment: My images are 228x228 and 152x152 so I don't think that's a problem. But you made a good point, when the images aren't square I don't think the resize method is suitable here.

Comment: can you save all the data you are using for training in a folder per label? Then you might see whether the input data is ok. But your question is about parameters for the LBPHFaceRecognizer, right?

Comment: Ah yes. My question is mainly about parameters for the recognizer.